# Flask-wtf can't set default value for DateTimeField

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm making a project on Flask and I need to set the default value for the *wtforms.DateTimeField()*

```py
def new_edit_task(task):
    class EditTask(FlaskForm):
        new_name = StringField('Name of task', validators=[DataRequired()], default=task.name)
        new_description = TextAreaField('Description', validators=[DataRequired()], default=task.description)
        new_deadline = DateTimeField("Deadline", format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M',
                                     default=task.deadline)
        new_link = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired()], default=task.link)
        submit = SubmitField('Отправить')
    return EditTask()
```

*task* is an SQLAlchemy model and *task.deadline* is *datetime.datetime* object.

That's how I render *new_deadline* field in HTML:

```
{{ form.new_deadline(class="half-width", type='datetime-local') }}<br>
      {% for error in form.new_deadline.errors %}
      <p class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                {{ error }}
            </p>
        {% endfor %}
```

*form* is *EditForm* object here

But it doesn't work. There is "dd.mm.yyyy --:--" on the page.

Can you please explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've solved the problem.

Instead of using *DateTimeField* and rendering this field with *type="datetime-local"*, I use *DateTimeLocalField* from *wtforms.field.html5*. And that's actually works!

Answer (score 0):

Your *task.deadline* returns just value from database. 
I suppose in dd.mm.yyyy format. 
Please note that *format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'* do nothing with default data. This pattern is for checking input data.

*task.deadline* value should be reformatted properly before using in form.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's wrong. I've checked this out using `print(type(task.deadline))`, it says, that: "<class 'datetime.datetime'>"

Comment: Ok, and what displays print(task.deadline) ?

Comment: It displays '2020-05-09 09:00:49.833915'. That's datetime.datetime.__str__ value

Comment: You use form.new_deadline(class="half-width", **type='datetime-local'**) in html-template. Is there handler for this type on template side?